# PyInstaller application black window on macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I made an appllication using Python  with PyInstaller, and it works well on my MacBook Air with macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, but when I try to run it on a MacBook Pro with MacOS Big Sur 11.1, it shows a window full of black, and nothing happens later, and nothing shows in Terminal even though I tried the .exe under /build , what's wrong with it?

Comment: Try running the application from command line instead of double-click, you may get an error log.

Comment: @May.D Oh, I tried, nothing displayed.

Comment: Have you tried building the application on the target computer ?

Comment: @May.D No, the target computer has no development environment, I borrowed from a friend for high performance test.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help without more information. You can try to add a very simple test like printing or writing to a file to see which piece of code is problematic.